# [NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null]. Not able to resolve Android-NDK error from a sample project related to PARALLEL-SPACE

Tags: java, android, c++, kotlin, android-ndk

Error Logs

> ### External native generate JSON release: executing ndkBuild Executable :
> /Users/nidhinagvanshi/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/ndk-build
> arguments :  NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
> APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/Users/nidhinagvanshi/Downloads/VirtualApp-master-2/VirtualApp/lib/src/main/jni/Android.mk
> NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/Users/nidhinagvanshi/Downloads/VirtualApp-master-2/VirtualApp/lib/src/main/jni/Application.mk
> APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16
> NDK_OUT=/Users/nidhinagvanshi/Downloads/VirtualApp-master-2/VirtualApp/lib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj
> NDK_LIBS_OUT=/Users/nidhinagvanshi/Downloads/VirtualApp-master-2/VirtualApp/lib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/lib
> APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false
>
> -n jvmArgs :
>
> /Users/nidhinagvanshi/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/build/core/add-application.mk:178:
> *** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See
> https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more
> information.    .  Stop. External native generate JSON release: using
> platform version 16 for ABI ARMEABI_V7A and min SDK version 14
> External native generate JSON release: rebuilding JSON
> /Users/nidhinagvanshi/Downloads/VirtualApp-master-2/VirtualApp/lib/.externalNativeBuild/ndkBuild/release/armeabi-v7a/android_gradle_build.json
> due to: External native generate JSON release: - expected json
> /Users/nidhinagvanshi/Downloads/VirtualApp-master-2/VirtualApp/lib/.externalNativeBuild/ndkBuild/release/armeabi-v7a/android_gradle_build.json
> file is not present, will remove stale json folder External native
> generate JSON release: - missing previous command file
> /Users/nidhinagvanshi/Downloads/VirtualApp-master-2/VirtualApp/lib/.externalNativeBuild/ndkBuild/release/armeabi-v7a/ndkBuild_build_command.txt,
> will remove stale json folder

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
MAIN_LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := va++

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wno-error=format-security -fpermissive -DLOG_TAG=\"VA++\"
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(MAIN_LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(MAIN_LOCAL_PATH)/Foundation
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(MAIN_LOCAL_PATH)/Jni

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Jni/VAJni.cpp \
                   Foundation/IOUniformer.cpp \
                   Foundation/VMPatch.cpp \
                   Foundation/SymbolFinder.cpp \
                   Foundation/Path.cpp \
                   Foundation/SandboxFs.cpp \
                   Substrate/hde64.c \
                   Substrate/SubstrateDebug.cpp \
                   Substrate/SubstrateHook.cpp \
                   Substrate/SubstratePosixMemory.cpp \

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -latomic
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := fb

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(MAIN_LOCAL_PATH)/fb/Android.mk
```

local.properties

> #Sat May 08 22:01:39 IST 2021 sdk.dir=/Users/nidhinagvanshi/Library/Android/sdk
> ndk.dir=/Users/nidhinagvanshi/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570

Comment: So have you fixed what it's complaining about here: _"APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared"_  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this error by downgrading NDK. The following line was changed in local.properties:

```
ndk.dir=/Users/nidhinagvanshi/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/17.2.4988734
```